# Construct redirect URL with RegEx

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, redirect

How to use Regex for redirecting example

`exemple.com/en/solution/platform-features` to

`exemple.com/en/platform-features`

Comment: You can do this without using regex too. Do you want to use regex to remove the second last directory name from the url?

Comment: I need to use regex expression to do 301 redirect that's what was asked by my employer, yes I want to remove /solution/ from my url

Comment: Will the word to be removed always be "solution"? If so, you can do this without regex. If not, you can still do this without regex if the format is going to be same as your sample.

Comment: no it will be different

Comment: How about something like `var tmp = url.Split('/'); tmp[tmp.Length - 2] = null; return string.Join("/", tmp.Where(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) == false));`? For starters. I'm sure this can be improved.

Comment: For future questions please avoid spending most of the post on thank you notes and "searched alot", instead clarify your sample and why/if you need particular technology (i.e. usually regex are used as hammer instead of picking more suitable tool). Also claiming that you watched youtube does not show any search efforts - ratio of educational/C# stuff there to random clips is somewhat high in favor of entertainment.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to always remove the third element then this should do it

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(?<Begin>([^/]*/){2})[^/]*/(?<End>.*)");
var match = reg.Match(@"exemple.com/en/solution/platform-features");
var result = match.Groups["Begin"].Value + match.Groups["End"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this; this is just a simple replace scenario. Although, to make it more flexible you could add configurable values for the involved parts something like this:

```
var pattern = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pattern"];
var replacement = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["replacement"];
var url = @"exemple.com/en/solution/platform-features";
var resultUrl = url.Replace(pattern, replacement);
return resultUrl;
```

And in your configuration file just put:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="pattern" value="/solution/" /> <!--Don't just replace "solution"-it can be another part of the url-->
    <add key="replacement" value="/" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks but I really need to use regex to 301 redirect in sitecore with the aliases I know it is noob question.

Answer (score 0):

```
/([^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$)
```

this regex will get what you want, but anyway you can always use the split function for / and join it back in c#

Comment: I am working on a Sitecore feature for my new job but never did .NET dev before so I am struggling, I need to be able to do 301 redirect with the aliases in sitecore with this regex string.